# Lambda does not work .. even though I have JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 set correctly, do I miss anything?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-debug

Lambda does not work with Android Studio:

This is what I have in gradle

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

These are the project settings

```
ext {

compileSdkVersion = 27
supportLibVersion = '27.1.0'
minSdkVersion = 27
targetSdkVersion = 27
```

}

This simple code is failing:

```
 button.setOnClickListener( (View x) -> Toast.makeText(
            getContext(), "Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    );
```

The cause, that does not make any sense to me:

```
   --------- Cause ---------

java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
```

The fatal error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method
```

Java version:
java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: r u able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your **lamba** is making issue, try it like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(
   getContext(), "Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
);
```